# How can I slide an input from a controller

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have created a sliding input. When the user activates the button, it goes to another view and returns to the view of the button, it is not pressed.
I need the button to keep the state.

I have used the ng-modal directive and from the controller I do $ scope.attributebutton = true; but it does not work

```css
input.vpn[type="checkbox"]{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-transition: 400ms all;
  transition: 400ms all;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #c4003b;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  width: 56px;
  height: 26px;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  animation: input 4s;
}
input.vpn[type="checkbox"]:checked, input.vpn[type="checkbox"].checked {
  background: #60c674;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px #6ABF76;
  transition: 250ms all;
}

input.vpn[type="checkbox"]::before {
  content:'';
  transition: 300ms all;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: auto;
  transform: translate(0,0);
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.06), 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.06), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.07), 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.06), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.11);
  animation: button 3s ease-out;
}

input.vpn[type="checkbox"]:checked::before, input.vpn[type="checkbox"].checked::before{
  transform: translate(20px,0);
}
```

```html
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <div ng-if="error.network.status=='success'">
        <h2> 
            <span class="pull-right">
                <input type="checkbox" class="vpn" ng-model="vm.activo" ng-click='changeVpn()'>
            </span>
            VPN
        </h2> 
    </div>
</div>
```

[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED817.png)

Comment: You are talking about "sliding input" or button when what you have is a toggle-styled checkbox, so what you want is the checkbox to be checked. I see it' s linked by `ng-model` to `vm.active`. If it is modified, you have to make the changes persistent by storing them in a database or at least in the localStorage, for example

Comment: you either need to store the state of the button in a database or sessionStorage or localStorage

Comment: Please update the with your controller code.

Answer (score 0):

The two simplest methods to save the frontend state is either local storage or state parameters.

### Local Storage

As mentioned in the comments, use local storage to save the previous state of the toggle button.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.vm = {};
  // Try loading previous toggle state on controller initialization
  $scope.vm.activo = localStorage.getItem('activo') || false;

  $scope.changeVpn = function() {
    // Do your change VPN stuff
    // Then save the toggle state
    localStorage.setItem('activo', $scope.vm.activo);
  };

}]);
```

This is the simplest option, but you may not always have access to local storage depending on the user's browser settings and other factors.

This is native JS. Docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

### UI Router

If you are using ui-router, you may also be able to retrieve it from the state parameters.

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state({ 
    name: 'main',
    url: '/main?activo',
    params: {
      // Using dynamic routing params to update address bar
      activo: { type: 'bool', value: false, dynamic: true }
    },
    template: '<div ng-app="..." ng-controller="myCtrl"><!-- Your template here --></div>',
    controller: 'myCtrl'
  });

}]);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) {

  $scope.vm = {};
  // Try loading previous toggle state on controller initialization
  $scope.vm.activo = $stateParams.activo || false;

  $scope.changeVpn = function() {
    // Do your change VPN stuff
    // Then update state parameters
    $state.go('.', { activo: $scope.vm.activo });
  };

}]);
```

This will update the address bar whenever the user toggles the button. When the user navigates away from the page, the toggle state will be saved in the browser history and loaded upon controller initalization.

See the ui-router docs for details: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/1.0.19/interfaces/params.paramdeclaration.html